# Saving specific attachment from Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook, attachment, email-attachments

I want to find e-mails with attachment named "IE529" or 599 or ZC and extension of .xml and save them to a folder on sharedrive.

Outlook seems to process the code, but neither of the attachments is saved.

Once this code works, I will think how to add parameter ".xml" into criteria.

```vb
Public Sub Komunikaty(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    
    Dim Zalacznik As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim KatalogIE529 As String
    Dim KatalogIE599 As String
    Dim KatalogZC299 As String
    
    KatalogIE529 -"xxxx"
    KatalogIE599 -"zzzz"
    KatalogZC299 -"yyyyy"
    
    For Each Zalacznik In MItem.Attachments
    
        If InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "IE529", vbTextCompare) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogIE529 & Zalacznik.DisplayName
        
        ElseIf InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "IE599", vbTextCompare) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogIE599 & Zalacznik.DisplayName
    
        ElseIf InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "ZC299", vbTextCompare) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogZC299 & Zalacznik.DisplayName
    
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

After applying some corrections, my code is saving attachments into given folder, but I cannot figure out, how to save only the attachments with extension ".xml".

I tried "AND", but afterwards it doesn't work.
It can either save xml or IE529.

How can I update this code, so it will search through xml files?

```vb
Public Sub Komunikaty(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    
    Dim Zalacznik As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim KatalogIE529 As String
    Dim KatalogIE599 As String
    Dim KatalogZC299 As String
    
    KatalogIE529 = "C:"
    KatalogIE599 = "C:"
    KatalogZC299 = "C:"
    
    For Each Zalacznik In MItem.Attachments
    
        If (InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "IE529", vbTextCompare)) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogIE529 & "\" & Zalacznik.DisplayName
        
        ElseIf InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "IE599", vbTextCompare) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogIE599 & "\" & Zalacznik.DisplayName
    
        ElseIf InStr(1, Zalacznik.DisplayName, "ZC299", vbTextCompare) Then
            Zalacznik.SaveAsFile KatalogZC299 & "\" & Zalacznik.DisplayName
    
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `"IE529" & "xml"` doesn't search for `IE529` and `xml` separately, it searches for `IE529xml`.

Comment: Without phrase "xml" at all, it still doesn't work. For the future, if we eventually make the formula work, how to create two parameters like "extension and phrase in the title"?

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger attached and go through each line of code line-be-line checking the results? What values do you pass exactly to the `SaveAsFile` method?

Comment: I've just added updated working code, but there is still question how to save only xml files through others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save only PDF attachments VBA Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076225/save-only-pdf-attachments-vba-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method accepts a string which specifies the location at which to save the attachment. Office applications are designed to deal with local disks only, so it makes sense to save the attached file to the local drive and then copy it where required (shared drive). Note, you need to specify the full file path (not relative) and make sure no forbidden symbols are presented in the string passed to the `SaveAsFile` method.

Also pay attention to the fact that attachments may not be presented on the item physically, only items with the [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type) property value set to the `olByValue` can be retrieved and saved to the disk (files). So, it makes sense to check the attachment type before calling the `SaveAsFile` method.

Comment: Hello, while providing filpath i put "-" instead of "=". Also I didnt include "& "\" &" while putting SaveAsFile.

Now code works fine, but I need to add additional parameter to filter only through attachmnets with extension xml.

Comment: You can check our the [Attachment.FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.filename) property which returns a string representing the file name of the attachment. So, you can check out the file extension and make a decision whether to save it or not.